# Uncaught ERROR Invalid hook call. While using "<Typical>" Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, portfolio

[image]I was developing a profile of my portfolio using ReactJS.
While I was using `typical` in my profile page as follows:

```
import "./Profile.css";
import Typical from "react-typical";

export default function Profile() {
  return (
    <div className="profile-container">
      <div className="profile-parent">
        <div className="profile-details">
          <div className="colz">
            <div className="colz-icon">
              <a #">
                <i className="fa fa-facebook-square" />
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i className="fa fa-linkedin-square" />
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i className="fa fa-instagram" />
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i className="fa fa-github-square" />
              </a>
            </div>
            <div className="profile-details-name">
              <span className="primary-text">
                Hello, I'M <span className="highlighted-text">ANUP</span>
              </span>
            </div>

            <div className="profile-details-role">
              <span className="primary-text">
                <h1>
                  <Typical //Error comes after i try to import this here
                  
                  />
                </h1>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There was no error in IDE's terminal, but it shows the following error in the browser:

> Uncaught runtime errors: × ERROR Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
> called inside of the body of a function component.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Hi. Can you please provide more of the error message including the stack trace? Thanks

Comment: Thank you sir for your response.. I updated a picture of the error message can you please review it?

Comment: What is your react version ? The `react-typical` library that you are using is compatible with only these versions of react `"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0"`.
If you are on a different react version than this, the error most probably be because of duplicate react versions

Comment: how should i proceed for the version "react": "^18.2.0",